# << was unexpected at this time in qTuio

Tags: qt, makefile

I am trying to make qTuio(https://github.com/x29a/qTUIO) on my windows machine. However, when I try to run make, it reports: "<< was unexpected at this time"

The full output is:

```
cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -Zi -MDd -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICO
DE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DOSC_HOST_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB
 -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT
_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"c:\OSGeo4W\include\qt4\QtCore
" -I"c:\OSGeo4W\include\qt4\QtNetwork" -I"c:\OSGeo4W\include\qt4\QtGui" -I"c:\OS
Geo4W\include\qt4" -I"..\..\tmp\debug" -I"..\..\tmp" -I"..\3rdparty\oscpack" -I"
..\3rdparty\tuio" -I"c:\OSGeo4W\include\qt4\ActiveQt" -I"..\tmp\debug" -I"." -I"
c:\OSGeo4W\apps\qt4\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008" -Fo..\tmp\debug\ @<<
<< was unexpected at this time.
make[1]: *** [{..}.cpp{..\tmp\debug\}.obj] Error 1
make: *** [debug] Error 2
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What version of make are you using for this? That looks like an nmake makefile.

Comment: @EtanReisner I am using GNU Make version 3.75.

Comment: Wow, that is *quite* old. Do you have nmake installed? Does running that work?

Comment: I actually do not have nmake installed. I will try to install it and test to see if it works.

Comment: By using nmake, it is reporting 'EOF' unexpected error.

Comment: which toolchain (cygwin? version) are you exactly using and can you post the commands to reproduce? also which compiler do you intend to use? i see msvc2008?

Comment: I intend to use msvc2008. I jut follow the guide in github. First run qmake and then run make.